# Escapeing values in PDO statements

Tags: php, pdo, prepare

Doesn't `prepare()` escape any `quotes(')` in a PDO statement ? For some reason when I do this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sessions (id, name) VALUES (1,'O'brian')";
$query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
```

I get this error:

```
Could not insert record SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'brian'.
```

How could this be if I'm using `prepare()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not passing the value in the execute method, it will not be automatically escaped for you. The following would be escaped for you:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sessions (id, name) VALUES (1, ?)";
$query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array("O'brian"));
```

Comment: Yay for prepared statements. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

> Doesn't prepare() escape any quotes(')
>   in a PDO statement?

No. In fact, there is no escaping being done by PDO at all. The whole point is to use bound parameters, therefore,  **no characters need to be escaped.**